# how to print only closed (available to use) port on a certain range?

Tags: linux, bash

I would like to create a bash script that check which port in my Linux server are closed and not in use from a specific range, port range (3000-3010).

the print output need to be only 1 port, and it will be nice if the output will be saved as a variable or in same file.

Comment: Maybe you could have a look to nmap utility.

Answer (score 0):

Using `netstat` you can check for what ports are **open** and this will help determine which are in that case **closed**. The following line will parse the netstat output looking for open ports in a specific range:

```
netstat -nau | awk -F'[[:space:]]+|:' 'NR>2 && $5>=3000 && $5<=3010'
```

The `-F'[[:space:]]+|:'` is the field separator
And `'NR>2 && $5>=3000 && $5<=3010'`checks for the range

You could subsequently redirect the output to a specific file ie adding `> ports.txt` to the end. If you want the result to be stored in a variable you could try:

```
ports=$(netstat -nau | awk -F'[[:space:]]+|:' 'NR>2 && $5>=3000 && $5<=3010')
```